# What's the `darwin` in Mac?

Tags: macos, python, darwin

In my Mac I execute the code:

```
import sys


print(sys.platform)
```

then get `darwin`, why it is not OSX. I don't know where to look for documentation on python sys module.

What's the `darwin` ?

Comment: Google "python sys module" for documentation.

Comment: Try also `uname -a` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Darwin is an open-source Unix-like operating system first released by Apple Inc. in 2000. It is composed of code developed by Apple, as well as code derived from NeXTSTEP, BSD, Mach, and other free software projects.

Darwin forms the core set of components upon which macOS (previously OS X and Mac OS X), iOS, watchOS, tvOS, and iPadOS are based. "

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)